# VSCode, why do I have to keep running the debugger to update my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Whenever I change something in my code and hit run, it runs the previous changes I made. In order for my new changes to be seen in my output, I have to manually debug my C++ file, and then hit run. It's very annoying. Anyway for me to fix this? I have never encountered this issue when working with Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you need to press "Build&Run"?

Comment: I don't normally use VSCode, but there must be a "Build" option somewhere. Have you looked in all menus? Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/)?

Comment: Python is a script language. This means, that it will be translated each time you hit 'Run'. C is a compiled language. Meaning you only see changes, when you hit 'Build' before hitting 'Run'.

Comment: Quimby Where can i find that?

Comment: VS Code apparently has a "save changes before compile" option, that is OFF by default.

Comment: @Belfast No idea, not using VSCode, I think there was some `launch.json` configuration? I'm sure one can find plenty of documentation online.

Comment: There is no "hot reload" or something comparable for C++, because it's a compiled language that is not interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Pyhton is an interpreted language. In simple terms, the Intpreter runs through the code and figures out what it has to do "on the fly". There is ususally no executable file created (*.exe on Windows), but the interpreter itself needs to be present on every PC you want to run your program on.

C++ is a compiled language. You need to feed you code to a compiler first, which produces an executable (skipping several intermediate steps here). Then you can run (& debug) that executable later at any point.

<strike>In Visual Studio, the default Hotkey for "Build&Run" is F5, which should compile your code and then start the debugger if succesful.</strike> In Visual Studio Code, starting the debugger does not execute the compiler. Installing an extension like Code Runner is your best bet here.

See also here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-compiled-and-interpreted-language/